# Changing default animation of Sheet on Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I'm developing a native cascades BB10 app using the Gold SDK.
When a 'Sheet' is displayed on BB10 it animates as a slide transition from the
bottom of the screen. Is it possible to override this transition and replace it with 
a fade transition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no simple way to override the animation.

If it works for your case maybe replace the sheet with a dialog? A dialog will be displayed on top of whatever is on the screen and you can easily add a fade in animation.

[https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb_*cascades*_dialog.html](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__dialog.html)